# Excel formula to sum conditionally

Tags: excel, sum, conditional-statements

[image]

Hi guys,

A simple one I guess. I want a formula that sum the amount of time shown at I11, L11, O11, etc. except if we see "Break Offshore" at the cell below.
My function is already shown at the function display but for some reason is not working.
Regards,
Carlos

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a range in `SUMIF`, so if "Break offshore" can't occur in other columns try using this formula

`=SUMIF(I11:X11,"<>Break Offshore",I10:X10)`

If that doesn't work you can use `SUMIFS` and include an extra criteria to sum only for relevant columns, i.e.

`=SUMIFS(I10:X10,I11:X11,"<>Break Offshore",I$9:X$9,"T*")`

Note that `SUMIFS` has a different order to `SUMIF` with the "sum range" first

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!